# Many 'postrender' and 'rendercomplete' events for a single VectorTile layer loading

Tags: openlayers, renderer, openlayers-6, vector-tiles

We added a new layer VectorTile with a style function to a PluggableMap (OpenLayers v6.4.3)

According to the doc:

- layer 'postrender' event is triggered after a layer is rendered
- map 'rendercomplete' event is triggered when rendering is complete, i.e. all sources and tiles have finished loading for the current viewport, and all tiles are faded in.

By logging those events in the console when loading this map (single VectorTile layer) we can see 6 layer 'postrender' events and 3 map 'rendercomplete' events.

It seems a layer 'postrender' event is fired after each rendered tile (from renderer/canvas/VectorTileLayer) of the layer and a map 'rendercomplete' is fired every 2 rendered tiles.

**How to detect when the layer is fully rendered, i.e. all tiles rendered?**

Answer (score 0):

The map should be completely rendered when the first rendercomplete event occurs.

I created a PR that should fix the duplicate rendercomplete events you observed.
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/11859

Comment: Can you confirm that the now updated version of OpenLayers (6.5.0) is supposed to fix this issue?

Comment: With 6.5.0, I actually still see many 'post render' and 'rendercomplete', no change from that point of view: how to detect when the layer is fully rendered, i.e. all tiles rendered?

Comment: The linked PR is included in v6.5.0.

Comment: There is an open issue with image layers: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11934, which I don't think is related to your issue. Could you provide a working example demonstrating your issue? You can modify any of the examples at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/ by clicking on the Edit button at top right.